sorting the groups made by group by clause using order by clause



first_name
age




john
31


john
25


betty
28



SELECT *
FROM Customers
GROUP BY first_name
ORDER BY age

it groups John.It somehow reached this after the query.



first_name
age




betty
28


john
31



why is it showing only one value of group john.
what i expected was



first_name
age




john
25


john
31


betty
28



there should be no order between john and betty.john should be sorted on basis of age and after that betty should come.but its showing one value per group and then sorting it according to age.

What are you trying to achieve? To group by the first_name means you want to do something with another column for every group of matching first_name, for example, do you want the sum/average/min/max age of each first_name? or you could return a count of how many have each first name, eg. 2 Roberts and 2 Johns, 1 of the rest?

Or are you trying to keep the records as separate rows, but simply keep them together with other matching names? then sort those by Age?

@GraemeLM i have editted the question.now can you help me?

@Ujjawal Why do you want to use GROUP BY? As your question currently stands, this makes no sense. Or did you miss to explain something?

@JonasMetzler i want to group data by names and then sort each group by age giving same names together and in ascending order by age.note i want names to appear in arbitrary fashion. Doing ORDER BY  name ,age appear that in ascending order of names and age as well

You can simply use order by to achieve the desired result, why are you focusing on using group by function?

The query is malformed and can only run in MySQL.

@Ujjawal GROUP BY is for aggregation, which will only show one of each value, then the aggregate of another column. Based on your updated "what I expected was" example, my answer below should return that exact result, using ORDER BY first_name,age

If you are trying to keep matching names together in the result list, but still as separate rows, sort by the first_name, then by the age:
SELECT first_name,age
FROM Customers
ORDER BY first_name,age

